# require(msg.sender.call("")): No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup

Tags: solidity-0.5.x

I am trying to compile the following Solidity program:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.9;  

contract Mutex {       
bool locked;        

modifier noReentrancy() {
      require(!locked);
      locked = true;
      _;
      locked = false;       
    
}     

function f() noReentrancy public returns (uint) {
        
        require(msg.sender.call(""));
        return 1;        
          
}  

}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
solc Mutex.sol Mutex.sol:13:7: Error: No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.
       require(msg.sender.call(""));
       ^-----^
```

Somebody, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior solc 0.5.0, `call` returns `bool`.

As of solc 0.5.0, `call` returns `(bool, bytes memory)`.

Since you're using solc 0.5.x, change this:

```
require(msg.sender.call(""));
```

To this:

```
(bool success,) = msg.sender.call("");
require(success);
```

Funny enough, your entire code appears (correctly) on [the official documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.0/contracts.html#function-modifiers).